# mounting vsphere 4.0 file system in ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, virtualization, mount

I am using VSpere 4.0 for my project work. I needed 4-5 servers my project work which is based on Database. I felt the virtualisation is very good to get the 5 servers running good at the same time. It was running good until few days back. Yesterday, it suddenly crashed and i had no idea of the reason.Today, it did not even boot up.

Now, i need to take the data backup from that system. In order to do the same, i got the hard drive from the machine and tried to mount it on local linux machine.But, i was not successful. The disk was not even recognized by the linux machine. Can some one please tell me how to mount it and get the required data?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](http://code.google.com/p/vmfs/) is a link to an open-source VMFS driver for Linux and Window. I can't say I've tried it but it sounds promising.